# AWS lambda CLI call does not return log messages except standard ones

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

In a simple "hello world" example I write to "console" several messages, like that:

```
Console.WriteLine("Function name: " + context.FunctionName);
Console.WriteLine("RemainingTime: " + context.RemainingTime);
```

When I call my function from CLI (either with `dotnet lambda invoke-function` or with `Invoke-LMFunction`), these console log messages do appear in CloudWatch, along with "standard" log events (START, END, REPORT).

[image]

But in the LogResult property of the response I do not get my log messages, only these 3 standard ones:

```
Log Tail:
START RequestId: c21e8947-1a7f-11e8-a331-5b75eed3283e Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: c21e8947-1a7f-11e8-a331-5b75eed3283e
REPORT RequestId: c21e8947-1a7f-11e8-a331-5b75eed3283e  Duration: 1117.28 ms    Billed Duration: 1200 ms        Memory Size: 256 MB   Max Memory Used: 25 MB
```

It seems that returned response just does not include log messages except for these 3 standard ones which AWS generates. Why does it happen? The documentation [says nothing about this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-logging.html):

> If you invoke a Lambda function programmatically, you can add the LogType parameter to retrieve the last 4 KB of log data that is written to CloudWatch Logs. For more information, see Invoke. AWS Lambda returns this log information in the x-amz-log-results header in the response. If you use the AWS Command Line Interface to invoke the function, you can specify the --log-type parameter with value Tail.

**Update:**
It seems that 2 other ways to write logs - `LambdaLogger.Log` and `context.Logger.Log/LogLine` do result in log messages appear in a `Tail`. So it's only `Console.Write/WriteLine` swallows them. If anyone knows why - I think it would be an answer to that question. Otherwise, it's not a blocker, we still have 2 other methods to use. But it would be great to know the difference.

Comment: Have you tried the `LambdaLogger` object?  The docs *say* that both are returned, but the wording is suspicious, to me: *"If you invoke a Lambda function via the console [...] the console displays the logs that the Lambda function writes using the LambdaLogger object. AWS Lambda also returns logs from Console.Write and Console.WriteLine methods."*  It seems weird that the `Console` methods also mentioned, yet they seem almost like sort of an afterthought, here.  Maybe it doesn't return these with `Tail`.  Strictly speculation on my part.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeah, kinda of. I've tried `context.Logger.Log()` method, but not the `LambdaLogger.Log()`. The outcome is the same, I see 2 pairs of messages in CloudWatch, and in a Tail only "standard" messages. I will try `LambdaLogger` though, who knows...

Comment: It's probably worth a try.  My Lambda expertise is Node but there's obviously quite a bit of magic involved in making these containers work as they do.  *"retrieve the last 4 KB of log data that is written to CloudWatch Logs"* strikes me as a potentially ambiguous phrase, as it would seem a little convoluted if Lambda writes to CloudWatch Logs and then polls CloudWatch logs to gather what it just wrote.  To me, this implies a place where some complexity might be hiding, as though multiple paths to the log might be reached via the different methods.  I read between the lines rather a lot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot argh, my bad, it appears that both `context.Logger` and `LambdaLogger.Log` return log messages in tail. Don't know how I missed that yesterday - it's been a late night :) But `Console.WriteLine` still doesn't do this. So I will update the question to highlight that it's only `Console.WriteLine` does not return messages in a Tail. Perhaps, someone will clarify why this happens. Thanks for your help!